# UITableView cell autoresizes some image views fed by AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking-2

I have UITableViewController with a basic cell. In my `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method implementation I set the `.imageView` property of my cell to get the data from the Internet, using AFNetworking 2.0 category: [UIImageView+AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h).

```
if (p.avatarPhoto) {
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:p.avatarPhoto placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo_frame.png"]];
}
```

When I do it, my table rows are properly generated and image is displayed, however its size changes when I highlight the row or scroll (so the rows reappear), like on this screen capture: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51630060/ScreenDemo-20131219-102840.mov

When I set the image to some bundled one, not one from the network, it works OK.

How should I set the image to have it working properly?

EDIT: The image I'm using for testing is this one: http://hollywoodvideo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/avatar-whatshisface.jpg. Maybe it's the matter of the aspect ratio of this image?

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar issue with AFNetworking 1 and I sorted it by create week reference to the cell and by called setNeedsDisplay. Please see belowe, it's AFNetworking 1 byt you can make it works for AFN.. 2.o:

```
__weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;

[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:p.avatarPhoto]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo_frame.png"]
                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                                   weakCell.imageView.image = image;
                                   [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
                               }
                               failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

                               }];
```

Comment: Yes, what appears to be happening is that the cell gets laid out for the placeholder.  When the loaded image is set with the new image, the cell still contains layout for the placeholder size instead of the new image size.